# How to decrement to number of hits on RateLimiter?

Tags: laravel, rate-limiting

I'm developing a ticket booking system using Laravel. When a user selects a ticket and clicks "Go to checkout," the chosen ticket gets locked for 6 minutes to prevent others from ordering it during the payment process. However, this system has a vulnerability in which a malicious user can lock all seats by repeatedly clicking the button.

To address this issue, I've attached a RateLimiter to the route that sends an API request to the bank. However, if the request has a validation error, the RateLimiter still increments the number of attempts, leading to a scenario in which a user may get blocked from the route for 6 minutes after entering incorrect information three times.

To prevent this from happening, I would like to implement a system that decrements the number of attempts if request validation fails. I've added an `unHit` method using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter`, but this function doesn't seem to decay, and if the number of attempts is already `0`, this function sets it to `-1.`

```php
public function unHit($key){
        return $this->cache->decrement($key);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the rate limiter in case of a human error instead of decrementing, as per your requirements. Laravel encodes the limiter key using the md5 algorithm and appends the rate limiter name. For your global limiter, the `$key` would be `md5('global'.$request->ip())`.

Code snippet for a middleware to handle this logic.

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    // If the response is a client error, clear the rate limiter
    if ($response->isClientError()) {
        // Generate the rate limiter key based on the global limiter and client IP
        $key = md5('global' . $request->ip());

        // Clear the rate limiter for the generated key
        RateLimiter::clear($key);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

In this example, if the response indicates a client error, the rate limiter for the user's IP will be cleared. This way, you can account for human errors and prevent users from being unnecessarily limited.

Hope this helps, Laravel documentation is not very clear about rate limiters to be honest.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/rate-limiting

Comment: But this way, one can send request n-1 times, then make an error. then his attempts are cleared and he can continue to send requests and lock tickets.

Comment: @Abw well, you still can implement your original approach, but you must check the numbers of hits first, otherwise you will get negative numbers when decrementing.